# Access Windows Server EC2 instance with WMI Exporter in Prometheus

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, prometheus, wmi

does anyone know what i'm doing wrong here? i'm trying to access my windows-server 2019 ec2 node locally so i can successful collect metrics via WMI Exporter and point this at my prometheus instance.I'm trying to access port 9182 for WMI Exporter, and can connect fine via localhost on my remote widows instance, also the IPv4 Address on the same instance.I've also tried to configure the firewall port on the windows host 9182. When I try to access via localhost this returns This site can’t be reached, if i try via public address on both i get Can’t reach this page. Ive opened port 3389 inbound and all traffic ipv4 outbound. Any help would be great. I have also tried adding RDP Ip directly to the inbound security rules, yet still have the same issue. Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After installing windows_exporter, the installer will create an inbound rule for windows_exporter itself. However it may be not enough and cause your issue for some reasons. See this [similar issue](https://github.com/prometheus-community/windows_exporter/issues/144).

Try to add a new inbound rule for the Windows firewall and let **any programs** can access the listening port (default 9182). That works for me.